# Bipod does not work at all anymore

Tags: battlefield-3

In BF3 on PC I remember using bipods early on, but since about december/januari they simply don't work at all anymore. The animation is not there and neither is the effect (I'm spraying all over the place with the machine guns).

I tried switching on and off the bipods on all kinds of guns. None work.

I tried picking up a kit from someone I saw using a bipod... nothing.

I know I need a flat surface, but even when I'm flat on the ground.

Is there a setting that could cause this? A bug? Do I need to reinstall BF3 completely?

Comment: What system are you playing on? I'm guessing by the reinstall suggestion that you are on PC.  So far i've only found people complaining about it.  Maybe a patch issue

Comment: It seems to me harder to set it up now, you now have to hold the gun parallel to the flat surface for a second or so before it gets set up.

Comment: @Samjus yes PC (edited question). It's not like I'm a big fan of bipods (have been playing without for half a year now...) but I did kind of like it to be honest. Just have to know what you're doing.

Comment: @Ric I'll give it another try, but I'm fairly sure I extensively tried that too.

Comment: As far as I remember, you cannot switch to bipod actively: It turns itself on when you lay your gun near a flat surface, and off again, when you move away. You don't even need to be in prone position.

Comment: I used one with the M40A5 like a week ago and it works pretty well. I don't know if there is an issue with MGs. Can you confirm that this only happens with MGs or with other rifles too? Keep in mind that you need to aim with rightclick to activate the bipod (required a flat surface as mentioned above).

Comment: @Streuner yep all guns. I know about flat surfaces (floor or stting behind a flat piece of wall or whatever). I have googled around and found noone with this problem.

Comment: @Jannes Did you try to repair your installation during origin?

Comment: One of the patches released earlier this year added the option to bind Deploy Bipod to a separate key than zoom. Have you tried going into the Key Bindings and making sure that Deploy Bipod is bound to something? Perhaps you could try changing it to a different key?

Comment: @Brysonic hmm.. that sounds like a setting I would have to check. I never knew they made a key binding for it... I kept hearing people complain about it, so I guessed they hadn't. Will check soon, thx!

Comment: @Jannes You're welcome, I hope that helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the patches released earlier this year added the option to bind Deploy Bipod to a separate key than zoom. I'd venture a guess that this command is either unbound or bound to a key that you're not aware of. Try changing the key for Deploy Bipod in the Key Bindings Menu and see if that fixes the problem.

[image: Bipod key bindings]

Comment: Isn't that one for the sniper attachment?

Comment: @Bora I'm pretty sure it works for every weapon that has a bipod, which includes most automatic weapons as well as sniper rifles.

Comment: Yep this was it: simple key binding... works perfectly now.  I totally missed that change when the update happened. Thanks!

Comment: @Jannes You're very welcome :-)